# Make Japanese text (Hiragana, Katakana and Kanji) visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, case

I'm creating a lyrics page for a Japanese song that includes Japanese lyrics, Romaji text and English translation. I worked out everything and I knew that Japanese text would be printed as undefined characters in webpage but I gave it a try. Question is how do I make it visible in the `<iframe>`?

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to do:

1. Save your html page with page encoding set to `UTF-8` without BOM encoding.
2. In your html page set: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` with this dtd: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

`meta charset` is by default set to UTF-8. So, step number 2 is not essential, but just in case you can keep.

Comment: @YashMJ: If it works, then please select the answer as Accepted, it will help others and stop other from answering same questions.

Comment: You don't need `<head>` section at all. https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags  Don't reference w3schools, they're the worst